# Error TS2552 trying to run out of the box SPA template in visual studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core

I am trying to start an Angular project using Visual Studio 17 Community Edition

I followed this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103) on installing the SPA templates. That process all seemed to go well.

I created a new project and hit F5, almost giddy w/ excitement.

The page flashes up (just like in the demo) for a second or so,  and then a modal overlay displays these errors:

```
 ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts:1406:33 
    TS2552: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'. Did you mean 'crypto'?
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.ts:1407:21 
    TS2552: Cannot find name 'msCrypto'. Did you mean 'crypto'?
```

I see msCrypto used in the vendor.js file, but I dont think that is where the problem is. 
Do i need to restore some other package?  Any help appreciated... thanks.

Comment: does it go away if your run an `npm install` in the ClientApp directory on the command line? VS should do that itself but it may take a few minutes

Comment: @greg Did you find a solution for this error? I have an old project built on angular2 and webpack that throws the exact same error. (Even line numbers are the same.)

Comment: no, i have given up trying to build an angular project in visual studio.  Have not tried in a few months.  I did notice there are new templates in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time finally caught up w/ this.  In VS 2019, you can simply open a folder that contains angular code.

I recommend launching it w/ the NG command prompt. In my experience, trying to let VS run it leaves TONS of junk running in memory.

You can however, benefit from all the features of the VS IDE. Not saying its the best, but I have used it forever and I know how to be productive in it.